# redirigir al login despues de perder la session en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un problema, necesito realizar lo siguiente.

Deseo redirigir al login automáticamente luego de que la sesión se haya perdido, 
tengo el middleware('auth') en cada uno de mis controladores pero esto solo funciona si el usuario hace algo luego de la sesion perdida. Lo que necesito es que ni bien se pierda sesion me rediriga al login inmediatamente. Gracias

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Tendrías que estar comprobando del lado del cliente si la sesión expira. Podrías utilizar algo como esto http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_3_material_design/ui_session_timeout.html que te ayude a verificar el tiempo de conexión. Documentación oficial https://github.com/maxfierke/jquery-sessionTimeout-bootstrap esto es solo un ejemplo, te sugiero que busques un complemento mas actualizado

Comment: Esta es la versión actualizada https://github.com/travishorn/session-timeout

Answer (score 1):

Eso se maneja en el método `__construct` de tu controlador con el siguiente código:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Si la autentifiión falla, redirige al usuario a `login` y después a la página que intentó accesar.

Comment: con este codigo dentro del contructor: $this->middleware('auth');
funciona lo que quiero saber es el momento exacto en el que se pierde la sesion para redirigirlo al login automaticamente.

Comment: La sesión tiene una fecha de expiración, puedes obtenerla/guardarla cuando la creas. El problema que veo es que la sesión es un archivo, y se accesa a el cuando tu aplicación pasa por el Middleware Auth, se me ocurre que cuando crees la sesión guardes la fecha de expiración en la BD y hacer algún trigger o algo por el estilo.